# Draw string inside rectangle visually

Tags: java, swing, text, rectangles, fontmetrics

I'm trying to display text inside a rectangle which I have the dimensions of (x, y, width, and height). However, if the text's length is long enough to the point where the text would leak outside the rectangle, I want to instead display as many characters as possible in a single line, followed by ellipses (...). I am aware that I can use the `Graphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text)` to get the width the text would occupy in pixels. I could use this method by looping through, adding a character at a time to the string that would be displayed and checking if its width exceeds the rectangle's width. However, this feels inefficient.

As such, I want to know if there is a better/efficient way of doing this.

Comment: *"a better/efficient way of doing this"* I don't know of one, but am not sure. Is it necessary to ensure only complete characters are depicted? If not, I'd check the length of the rendered string and if over the width limit, apply a clip to the graphics object before drawing it. As an aside, will the code add a tooltip to display the complete text? If not, how does the user know (for sure) what the missing text is?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I would prefer that complete characters are depicted as a character cut in half followed by ellipses would look weird. Still, I thank you for your clipping suggestion as I was not aware of that being a possible approach. As for displaying the missing text, the user can click on the rectangle to open a preview displaying the entire text.

Comment: *"a character cut in half followed by ellipses would look weird."* Yep. Even when I tried to imagine it, I could see there would be some weird consequences. E.G. a truncated 'o' looking like a 'c'.

Comment: I would suggest you should loop using the `charWidth(...)` method to get the width of each character. I suspect the stringWidth(...) method needs to loop through all the character in the string so you don't want to keep doing that. FWIW that is how I did this type of logic in the [Left Dot Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/).

Comment: @LeftDotRenderer, that's a clever idea. Thanks for that. Will look into it 

Comment: I think you mean @camickr. If you are doing it correctly, the ID should appear on the upper left as the letters are typed & you can simply click it.

Comment: You could do some math.  Say your rectangle is 500 pixels wide and you want to display a 100 character string.  You calculate that the entire 100 characters would take up 625 pixels.  Calculate the width divided by the calculated width (500 / 625) and multiply the result by the number of characters (100) which gives 80.  See if 80 characters fit.  You can iterate a few more times if you want the maximum number of characters in the string, otherwise, this should lead to a good approximation.

Comment: The problem you need to beware of is, not every character is the same width in many fonts, so, unless you’re using a fixed width font, it might be more worthwhile to iterate over the string (remember you need “…”)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Thank you. I thought something was weird when his name didn't show up but didn't think much of it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, That's an interesting idea. But in terms of efficiency, I wonder if it is better than camickr's since using your idea, the `stringWidth()` method would be called multiple times, looping over each character and calculating its width multiple times, essentially repeating calculations. However with camickr's idea, all characters are only parsed once. Still, I thank you for you suggestion. Now I have multiple solutions to choose from.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, You are absolutely right. While it would be much easier to use a font with fixed width for each character, I wish to devise an algorithm that works for any font. Still, I appreciate your input.

Comment: If you’re worried about efficiency, I’d consider caching the results, so, unless the rectangle changes or the text or the font, you can reuse the text